# Can a Jamaica obtain a transit visa for Canada, and how long does the process take?

Tags: transit, canada, jamaican-citizens

I am a Jamaican who will be travelling from Spain to Jamaica soon. The cheapest route is through Canada so that’s why I am interested.

Comment: Where are you travelling from/to? Are you asking about a visa to transit in Canada? http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp

Comment: I am travelling to jamaica. Yes I am asking about tramsit visa Canada

Comment: I am travelling from Spain to jamaica

Answer (score 3):

Jamaican citizens are eligible to apply for a transit visa. If you have less than 48 hours between flights AND you’re just transiting, a transit visa is free.

If you have more than 48 hours between flights OR if you decide to visit Canada, you need a visitor visa, which costs $100 CAN.

According to the Canadian Government website, current processing times for valid applications in Jamaica are 15 days, plus the time you need to give biometrics and the time it takes to send an application between a Visa Application Centre and the decision-making office. From Spain, it’s 28 days.

You don’t need an eTA in either case.

Source: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp